# How to update price based on number of quantity using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to create a shopping cart where a client select an item from the autocomplete search automatically added to cart.and based on the number of quantity price can be updated. I have added to the cart successfully but I couldn't update the price dynamically.
Can anyone point me out what's the error with the existing code:

```
$('#searchName').autocomplete({
    source: '{!! asset('nameAutocomplete') !!}',
    select:function(suggestion,ui){
        event.preventDefault();
        var $tbody = $('#example tbody');
        $tbody.append('<tr><td class="id">' + ui.item.id +
            '</td><td class="name">' + ui.item.value +
            '</td><td class="price" id="price">' + ui.item.price +
            '</td><td><input type="text" id="quantity" value="1"/></td><td><input type="text" id="total" readonly value="'+ui.item.price+'" class="readonly"/></td></tr>');

        $('#quantity').on('keyup',function(){
            var tot = ui.item.price * this.value;
            $('#total').val(tot);
        });  
    }                   
});
```

Here is the table part code :

```
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered"  id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>                        
            <td>ID</td>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Price</td> 
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Total</td>                     
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Error I'm getting :

[image]

Comment: every row has an element with the same id of "quantity"

Comment: `id`s are to be unique, but you will have `n` number of `id="quantity"` & `id="total"`. So how do you think javascript will know which `$('#quantity')` or `$('#total')` you are selecting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check with following code,I added little bit to @Mayank code,

```
     var $tbody = $('#example tbody');
        $tbody.append('<tr><td class="id">' + ui.item.id +
        '</td><td class="name">' + ui.item.value +
        '</td><td class="price">' + ui.item.price +
        '</td><td><input type="text" class="quantity" value="1"/></td><td><input type="text" class="total" readonly value="'+ui.item.price+'" class="readonly"/></td></tr>');


        $('.quantity').on('keyup',function(){
           //Corrected part
            var tot = $(this).parent().prev().html() * this.value;
           //var tot = ui.item.price * this.value;
           //Assume that you are getting correct value to tot variable
           $(this).parent().next().find('.total').val(tot);      
        });
```

Comment: The problem about your code is total updated based on quantity but not in  the exact row name. means total updated based on last item price while i change the quantity

Comment: I update the code. Please check. You're correct. Because it gets the same price. I changed the code little bit.

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes in code like:

```
var $tbody = $('#example tbody');
$tbody.append('<tr><td class="id">' + ui.item.id +
    '</td><td class="name">' + ui.item.value +
    '</td><td class="price">' + ui.item.price +
    '</td><td><input type="text" class="quantity" value="1"/></td><td><input type="text" class="total" readonly value="'+ui.item.price+'" class="readonly"/></td></tr>');

    // Use class in place of id, as you cannot work with id for multiple occurance of same html

$('.quantity').on('keyup',function(){
    var tot = ui.item.price * this.value;
    $(this).find('.total').val(tot);    // Use DOM traverse to get the next <input type="text" /> and put new total value to it
});
```

Comment: I got total for the first time but when i update the quantity ..it couldn't update the total price with your code.

Comment: @Hola I added an answer. Hope that will help you.